# Apply script to a calendar view every date navigation

Tags: javascript, office-365, custom-list, css, calendar

I have a calendar view in Sharepoint Online and my user wants the time hidden.

[image: CalendarView]

I manage to hide this using Javascript but the problem is that when I navigate to another month view, the script no longer works. Is there any way to refresh or reload the script to hide the time.

Please help. Thanks!

Additional:

Here is the script.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the script?

Comment: I've done this before using [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) in javascript. might not be the best  but with a few logical statements this will take minimal usage.

Comment: @NadeemYousuf - I already edited the question and added the script.

Comment: Hello @Vince2322589, I tried using setInterval but an error appears.  Expected ']' is the error. I dont know why this occurs when I just added a setInterval function in my script.

Comment: Does it hide the time and then after you receive the error? you might be hiding the div and then when the interval starts again it tries to wrap the div again?

Comment: Yes @Vince2322589, it hides the time. Maybe you are right but when I navigate to another month the time appears again. And the error keeps on showing up.

Comment: In the code you posted I don't see you setting the value for v. You might need to set v each time the interval starts. As it could be looking for the old v. try setting alerts to see if it is using the correct values?

Comment: Hello @Vince2322589, please help me on this. How can I set this v every time the interval starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Vince2322589 help, I found the solution to this by just using setInterval method and minor modification on my script.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Set [interval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) javascript function and calling your variables again you should be able to hind the time as required.

After you have called your variable do a statement to check if it has been set previously so as to not wrap the div again.

You set the variable v by assigning it again to the variable